For about 3,600 blocks, the ZERO address is listed as miner, what happens to TX fees & rewards?
Example: Early Days Block# 5305 - https://etherscan.io/block/5305

Example: Recent Block# 20211132 https://etherscan.io/block/20211132
PRE/POST merge:
Is there a way to figure out the actual miner ? 
Are block rewards burnt, never existed, or sent to a real address ? \
Dune Analytics Reference:
All ZERO Address mined blocks - https://dune.com/queries/3891845

similar: Is it possible for the miner of a block to be address 0x0?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PatMyron My question asks what happens to TX fees and rewards.  That question also incorrectly states in one of the answers only low blocks have the zero address as a miner.
